# Plotting with secondary axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to overlay a bar graph (primary axis) and line (secondary axis), but I keep getting an error that I don't understand how to fix. I have tried to follow multiple examples from other questions, but I'm still not getting the result I need.

Here's my code:

```
ggplot(data = MRIP, aes(x = Length_mm)) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = Perc.of.Fish), stat="identity", width = 10, fill = "black") + 
    geom_line(aes(y = Landings), stat = "identity", size = 2, color = "red") +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "Percentage", sec.axis = sec_axis (~./Landings, name = "Landings"))
```

How do I fix this error: "Error in f(...) : object 'Landings' not found"?

Comment: Hello Stacy, welcome to StackOverflow. Please, could you share a sample of your data? You can type `dput(head(MRIP))` in your console and copy the output in your question. That will help us to help you.

Comment: structure(list(MRIP = c("FINAL", "FINAL", "FINAL", "FINAL", "FINAL", 
"FINAL"), Estimation.Methodology = c("MRIP (2015 - 2019)", "MRIP (2015 - 2019)", 
"MRIP (2015 - 2019)", "MRIP (2015 - 2019)", "MRIP (2015 - 2019)", 
"MRIP (2015 - 2019)"), Year = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L), Common.Name = c("ATLANTIC CROAKER", "ATLANTIC CROAKER", 
"ATLANTIC CROAKER", "ATLANTIC CROAKER", "ATLANTIC CROAKER", "ATLANTIC CROAKER"
), FL_cm = 22:27,

Comment: Perc.of.Fish = c(0.89, 5.24, 0.2, 2.2, 23.04, 
11.38), Landings = c(3017.78, 17756.99, 692.7, 7473.9, 78119.15, 
38565.94), PSE = c(100, 69.8, 100, 98.6, 45.2, 75.1), Length_mm = c(220, 
230, 240, 250, 260, 270)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
coef <- 4000
MRIP %>% 
    mutate(LandingsPlot=Landings/coef) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Length_mm)) +
    geom_col(aes(y = Perc.of.Fish), width = 10, fill = "black") + 
    geom_line(aes(y = LandingsPlot), size = 2, color = "red") +
    scale_y_continuous(
      name = "Percentage", 
      sec.axis = sec_axis (trans= ~.*coef, name = "Landings")
    )
```

Giving

[image: modified plot]

Why does this work? The scale factor used to define the secondary axis cannot be part of the input data.frame - because if it were, it could potentially vary across rows (as it does here).  That would mean you had a separate scale for each row of the input data.frame.  That doesn't make sense.  So, you scale the secondary variable to take a similar range to that of the primary variable.  I chose `coef <- 4000` by eye.  The exact value doesn't matter, so long as it's sensible.

Having *divided* by the scale factor to obtain the plotted values, you need to *multiply* by the scale factor in the transformation in order to get the correct labels on the secondary axis.

Thank you for providing a good MWE.  But next time, for extra marks, please post the results of `dput()` in your question rather than in the comments...

**Update**
To answer OP's follow up question in the comments:  legends are linked to aesthetics.  So to get a legend, move the attribute that you want to label inside `aes()`.  You can then define and customise the legend using the appropriate `scale_<aesthetic>_<type>`.  However it's worth noting that if you write, say, `aes(colour="black")` then `"black"` is just a character string.  It doesn't define a colour.  (Using the standard defaults, it will in fact appear as a slightly pinkish red, labelled "black"!)  This can be confusing, so it might be a good idea to use arbitrary strings like `"a"`, `"b"` and `"c"` (or `"Landings"` and `"Percentage"`) in the aesthetics.  Anyway...

```
coef <- 4000
#Note fill and color have moved inside aes()
MRIP %>% 
  mutate(LandingsPlot=Landings/coef) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Length_mm)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = Perc.of.Fish, fill = "black"), width = 10,) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = LandingsPlot, color = "red"), size = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Percentage", 
    sec.axis = sec_axis (trans= ~.*coef, name = "Landings")
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red"), labels=c("Landings"), name=" ") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("black"), labels=c("Percentage"), name=" ")
```

Gives

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful! I'm sorry, clearly I'm new to R and Stack Overflow. I will put it in my question next time! Thanks again!

Comment: I have one more question, how do I add a legend to this to show that the bars are percentage and the line is landings?